# Are Ada Tasks supported on RISC-V FE310-G002?

Tags: ada, riscv

I need tasking for my next project but I'm not sure if all Ada features are available for RISC-V. There is a LED blink example here but not much more.

https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library/blob/master/examples/HiFive1_rev_B/src/main.adb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked AdaCore. They responded as follow:

> Tasking (Ravenscar) on the FE310 is not supported yet.
>
> The next release of GNAT Community will most likely provide support
>   for tasking on the RISC-V64 SiFive Unleashed board.

/2020-05-12

Comment: If you need it before then, you may consider attempting a port of another (probably ARM) RTS to the RISC-V. If FreeRTOS is supported on your platform this one from Simon Wright may be worth looking at, but the port may take non-trivial effort. https://github.com/simonjwright/cortex-gnat-rts

Answer (score 3):

You would need a runtime that supports tasking. AdaCore has a collection of Bareboard runtimes for small, embedded devices at

https://github.com/AdaCore/bb-runtimes

There is some RISC-V support there, including what looks to be [Ravenscar](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-13.html) tasking (a subset of the full Ada tasking model)